# Google Sites page never shows up in Google Search organic results?

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search, pagerank, google-sites

I use Google Sites (i.e.: https://sites.google.com/site/EXAMPLE/ ) as a convenient way to maintain up-to-date info on several residential properties, info that's often requested by my property agents, its been around for about 1 year, but I still can never get it to appear in organic Google search results or Bing, even if I search the specific keywords such as the street names.

I submitted the URL manually to search engines, knowing that my Sites page probably has very few incoming links.

Is this expected behavior?

The content of my page has simple formatted text, and outgoing links to Picasa/G+/imgur photo albums.

Am I doing something wrong or do all GoogleSites pages have poor organic search rank?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you google "sites.google.com", then it lists plenty of sites hosted there.

However, as it is not using sub-domains to create the URLs, search engines will most likely see each site as simply a sub-page of the single massive sites.google.com website (with  53,900,000 results in the listings), rather than a website of its own (with a dozen or so pages).  This isn't going to really give it great SEO unless you have lots of good links pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Google sites can show and rank in search engines like any other, example search result below.

[image]

Comment: My question is about Google **Sites** the Google product (note the uppercase S for "Sites").

Comment: I know, and I showed a google site returning high in search results along with others.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I saw the one titled "FAQ: Webmaster Tools..." but not very relevant to my question, since that seems to be maintained by Google themselves. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Makes no difference that it is maintained by google ! Here is another google sites ranking in any case : https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Nobuyuki+Tsujii